# SpringBoot Zuul gateway over HTTPS

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have all my infrastructure orchestrated (Zuul API Gateway + Eureka Service Discovery + Business Microservices) running on http.
The problem comes when I want my Zuul Gateway to receive requests on 443 through https instead http on port 80.

My intention is to receive requests through Zuul on https but comunication with Eureka and the other Microservices to keep it on http like until now.

Adding following properties on my application.yml on Zuul gateway makes it work fine over https, but Ribbon cannot get routes anymore from Eureka, neither Actuator endpoints are available anymore as they require https now, although Zuul registers successfuly on Eureka.

```
application.yml    
   server:  
      port: 443  
      ssl:  
        enabled: true  
        key-store: classpath:certificate.p12  
        key-alias: tomcat  
        key-store-password: ******  
        key-store-type: PKCS12*
```

Any idea how to properly set this configuration?

Thanks.